# Date manipulation Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created an Events Model with the event date.

So when I display it I want it to show :

1. "Tomorrow" ( If the event date is tomorrow )
2. "This week" ( If the event lies within this week )
3. "Next week" ( If the event lies next week )
4. "This month" ( You get the idea )

What is the easiest method of doing this? Is there any "gem" out there to help me with this?

Comment: There are some helpers built into rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html but I don't think they support your specific use case. You could check for some gems on rubytoolbox: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=date - also you might want to checkout my blog post on rails and timezones, there are a lot of subtle issues that can occur: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: So there is no easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution here would be to write your own helper. I'm not going to do the whole thing for you, but this should get you started.

Add this to your `application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_date(date)
    tomorrow = Time.current.beginning_of_day + 1
    day_after_tomorrow = tomorrow + 1
    end_of_week = Time.current.end_of_week

    if date >= tomorrow && date < day_after_tomorrow
      'Tomorrow'
    elsif date >= day_after_tomorrow && date <= end_of_week
      'This week'
    else
      'Some other date'
    end
  end
end
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient way of writing this, but I wanted to keep things relatively simple.

Then in your view, just use the helper to format your date:

```
<%= format_date(@event.date) %>
```

**EDIT**

Updated to use `Time.current`. Thanks to @house9 for the tip.

Comment: I had previously considered that but discarded it since we're taking the date boundaries. You're quite right though - late night/early morning use of this would provide unexpected results without zimezone support.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying the same thing, except I put the code in the controller. Yes, helper is the best place to put it.